# How to know port assigned to DatagramSocket by OS

Tags: java, android

I can initialize a [DatagramSocket](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getPort()) with a zero arg constructor, and the OS will choose the port number for the socket

```
DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
```

But when I call `getPort()` on the socket, the result returned is `-1`

So I'm just wondering, is it even possible to know the port number assigned to the socket by the OS?

Comment: Have you considered reading the [Javadoc you cited](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getPort())?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it via [`getLocalPort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/DatagramSocket.html#getLocalPort()).

Rather a trivial question.

Comment: Maybe a less trivial question is why have a method called `getPort` when there is also a method called `getLocalPort`?